# how do I install brackets in centOs 7?

Tags: centos

I want to intstall brackets editor in cent Os 7 .. please someone help me... thanks...

I've tried to install by converting the .deb file of brackets to .rpm using wine but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

`brackets` is available on [COPR repo](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/) , you can [enable](https://docs.pagure.org/copr.copr/how_to_enable_repo.html#how-to-enable-repo) it as follows:

```
yum copr enable jgillich/brackets
```

Also you need to have `yum-plugin-copr` installed:

```
 yum install yum-plugin-copr
```

Update and install `brackets`:

```
yum update
yum install brackets
```